# Short exact sequence of groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $1\to N\xrightarrow{\text{i}} G\to H\to 1$ be a short exact sequence of groups. Let $f:G\to N$ be a group homomorphism such that $fi: N\to N$ is an isomorphism.

What are some "good" things we can say about the group $G$? For instance if $fi=1_N$, then we have a direct product. What about the above general situation?

Comment: You can replace i in the exact sequence with its composition with the inverse of fi.

Comment: To clarify @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez's comment, replacing $i$ with $i' = i(fi)^{-1}$ yields a short exact sequence for which $fi' = 1_N$, and hence $G$ is always a direct product of $N$ and $H$.

Comment: Thank you, that was easy, I should have thought of that one. Perhaps one of you can make it as an answer and I will accept it, otherwise this will remain unanswered. Thanks.